# Invoice No LAN Automation ? [Increment by 1]

Tags: c#

I would like to find a soluttion to my problem for invoice number automation.
And I have 3 users connected via LAN. Now everybody can save at same time.
But the number has to be increment by priority.

I also did already, but not satisfied....hence I need better advise...

The confusion is that I use to save like the below...

```
    var InvoiceVar1 = InvoiceDAp.InsertCommand.Parameters;
    InvoiceVar1.Add("@invoice_no", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10,"invoice_no");
    var InvoiceVar2 = InvoiceDAp.UpdateCommand.Parameters;
    InvoiceVar2.Add("@invoice_no", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10,"invoice_no");
```

So where to increase the invoice_no by 1, of its max(invoice_no)...?

Thanks

Comment: huh? You want to do this with a simple SQL statement yes? Why not write a stored procedure and do this on the sql-server?

Comment: use auto increment feature of sql server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not put an [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column in your database.

That way the column will increment automatically as new rows are inserted.